# Looping while in a loop of for

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm handling a code, and i have a problem:

The loop with for doesn't work with while.

**It mean after run with i = 0, execute the script then the code stop.**

Expectation: the code can run **continually** with **i= 0,1,2,3, so on..**

So how can i modify the code to work like that way, please help, thank you very much.

```js
function FOLDER_SCAN_ONLY() {
  // List folders inside the folder  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("scan_results")
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("folder_to_scan");

  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i in data; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    if (!rowData[1]) continue;
    if (rowData[2] != 'OK') continue;
    if (rowData[3] != '') continue;
    var folder_id = rowData[1];
    var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id)
    var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
    while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
      var childFolder = childFolders.next()
      var data = [
        childFolder.getName(),
        childFolder.getUrl(),
        childFolder.getId(),
        childFolder.getParents().next().getName()
      ];
      // Write
      ss.appendRow(data)
      sheet.getRange(2 + i, 4).setValue('done')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use both of the loops, they probably behave different to how you'd expect though.

```
function forWhileLoop(){
for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++){
  loop = true
  console.log(`processing: ${i}`)
  while (loop == true){
    console.log(`loop is ${loop}`)
    loop = false
    console.log(`loop is ${loop}`)
  }
  }
  console.log('all done')
}

forWhileLoop()

// Results in 

processing: 0
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 1
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 2
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 3
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 4
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 5
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 6
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 7
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 8
loop is true
loop is false
processing: 9
loop is true
loop is false
all done

https://repl.it/repls/EnormousNegligibleTechnology
```

Answer (score 1):

The while loop will only run while the condition is true, but it will check at least once per cycle from the for loop. If you want it to run every time, you could change it to a do while loop. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you can definitely put a while loop inside of a for loop.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  console.log('Starting a cycle');
  let bool = true;
  let value = 0;
  while(bool){
    console.log('While loop');
    if(value === 3){
      bool = false;
    } else {
      value += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

When executed, this will provide you with an example--

```
Starting a cycle
While loop
While loop
While loop
While loop
Starting a cycle
While loop
While loop
While loop
While loop
Starting a cycle
While loop
While loop
While loop
While loop
Starting a cycle
While loop
While loop
While loop
While loop
Starting a cycle
While loop
While loop
While loop
While loop
```

So as you can see the while loop will run every cycle of the for loop-- assuming it's condition is true. If the condition goes false in the first while loop, but never becomes true again, the while loop will be skipped for all future cycles of the for loop.

For example if we change the code slightly..

```
let bool = true;
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  console.log('Starting a cycle');
  let value = 0;
  while(bool){
    console.log('While loop');
    if(value === 3){
      bool = false;
    } else {
      value += 1;
    }
  }
```

In this case we set the condition for the while loop once, but never changed it back to its default. Now we get...

```
Starting a cycle
While loop
While loop
While loop
While loop
Starting a cycle
Starting a cycle
Starting a cycle
Starting a cycle
```